# how to access parents method through subclass object in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-runtime

Class1.h:

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
-(void) update;
@end
@interface Class1 (Private) -(void) private1; -(void) private2; @end
```

Class1.m:

```
@implementation Class1

-(void) update
{
    [self private1];
    [self private2];
}

-(void) private1
{
    // some code
NSLog(@"i used in class2"); }

-(void) private2
{
    // another code
NSLog(@"me too used in class2"); }

@end
```

Class2.h:

```
@interface Class2 : Class1

@end
```

Class2.m:

```
@implementation Class2

@end
```

main.m:

```
int main()
{

Class2 *class=[[Class2 alloc]init];

[class update];

}
```

The question is: I inherited class2:class1 like this
,now i want to access the method update that present in class1 through class2 object "class".
but i give me warning ..why is this happening?? 
why i am not accessing that?? 
plz tell me about this with full explanation

Comment: That should work.  What's the exact warning?

Comment: Always include the *exact* and *complete* error message.

Comment: all work fine now....i don't know what the problem was..?? it's work fine now

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work; you can access `update` via the subclass.

In the absence of the exact error message I'm gonna guess it's that the compiler doesn't know about `Class2` as you haven't added the following in `main.m`:

```
#import "Class2.h"
```

(and for that matter `#import "Class1.h"` in `Class2.h`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Class2 *class=[[Class alloc]init];
```

You are supposed to use `Class2` here not `Class`. Might be a typo. One more thing `Class` is a data type in ObjC. May be its warning you. Do like

```
Class2 *class=[[Class2 alloc]init];
```

Comment: sorry...typing mistake there is class2

Comment: then mention the warning msg?

Comment: Don't use `Class` for a class name, unless you mean it.